# Destructuring object and ignore one of the results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring, ecmascript-next

I have:

```
const section = cloneElement(this.props.children, {
  className: this.props.styles.section,
  ...this.props,
});
```

Inside `this.props`, I have a `styles` property that I don't want to pass to the cloned element.

How can I do?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the [object rest/spread syntax](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread):

```
// We destructure our "this.props" creating a 'styles' variable and
// using the object rest syntax we put the rest of the properties available
// from "this.props" into a variable called 'otherProps' 
const { styles, ...otherProps } = this.props;
const section = cloneElement(this.props.children, {
  className: styles.section,
  // We spread our props, which excludes the 'styles'
  ...otherProps,
});
```

I assume that you already have support from this syntax based on your code above, but please be aware that this is a proposed syntax which is made available to you via the [babel stage 1 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/). If you get syntax errors on execution you can install the preset as follows:

```
 npm install babel-preset-stage-1 --save-dev
```

And then add it to the presets section of your babel configuration. For example in your .babelrc file:

```
 "presets": [ "es2015", "react", "stage-1" ]
```

---

*Update based on comment on question by OP.*

Okay, so you say that you already have a `styles` variable declared before this block?  We can manage this case too.  You can rename your destructured arguments to avoid this.

For example:

```
const styles = { foo: 'bar' };

const { styles: otherStyles, ...otherProps } = this.props;
const section = cloneElement(this.props.children, {
  className: otherStyles.section,
  // We spread our props, which excludes the 'styles'
  ...otherProps,
});
```

Comment: I don't think this works out of the box with the react preset. It would be useful if you explained how to configure Babel to make use of this.

Comment: This is a really creative answer, I didn't know this was possible with the spread operator

Comment: You could also destructure directly into className like this: `const { styles: { section: className }, ...otherProps } = this.props;`.

Answer (score 34):

You could use [Object Rest Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) magic.

```
const props = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const { a, ...propsNoA } = props;
console.log(propsNoA); // => { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

So in your case it would be:

```
const { styles, ...propsNoStyles } = this.props;
const section = cloneElement(this.props.children, {
  className: this.props.styles.section
  ...this.propsNoStyles,
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the same answer provided by @ctrlplusb

Comment: @am0wa this is all ok but then the es-lint or others cry because i just wanted to ignore the first one... haven't found a good way to have it vanish and make linters happy

Comment: @RangerReturn you could use `// tslint:disable-next-line`

Answer (score 1):

I like ctrlplusb's answer, but here is an alternative using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) if you don't want to add a new babel preset:

```
const section = cloneElement(this.props.children, {
    className: this.props.styles.section,
    ...Object.assign({}, this.props, {
        styles: undefined
    })
});
```

Comment: Then you have an undefined property

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference for your application.  If you try to access a `prop` that was not passed to your component, the value would be `undefined` anyways.  This is almost equivalent, provided you don't rely on the existence of a particular key supplied to your props.

Answer (score 1):

or you can do something like this...

```
var newProp = (this.props = {p1, p2,...list out all props except styles});
```

Comment: This is bad at so many levels.