# How to select all props but one from object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanna to select all props but one from a javascript object but doing in elegant way using ES6, is this possible?

example:

```
const myObj = { prop1, prop2, prop3 }
const newObj = {
…myObject.remove(prop3)
}
```

then newObj should be `{ prop1, prop2}`

if destruct I can select some, or all

```
const newObj = {
…myObject
}

const {prop1, prop2} = myObjct
```

but I dont know how to select all but one.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838778/destructuring-object-and-ignore-one-of-the-results?

Comment: or you can simply do `delete newObj.prop3` if you want to modify the original object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [object rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to assign all other properties to `newObj`, except those explicitly stated:

```js
const myObj = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2, prop3: 3 }

const { prop1, ...newObj } = myObj

console.log(newObj)
```