# How can I push the state to an array with specific items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have in the state most of the item I wanted to push it in an array

and I want to push all state to except some item

so here's my state

```
state = {
    username: '..',
    date: '..',
    time: '..',
    description: '..',
    images: '..',
    buildingNumber: '..',
    status: '..',
    serviceDB: '..',
    snapshotKey: '..', // i don't need this when pushed
    count: -1, // i don't need this when pushed
  };
```

here's my code

```
 let order = [];
    order.push(this.state);
    console.log(order); it's log all state 

// I want to push it to DB
    database()
      .ref(`Providers/ProvidersOrders/${uid}`)
      .push(...order);
  };
```

Comment: `const { snapshotKey, count, ...filteredData } = this.state;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to destructure an object into a new object in es6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381557/is-there-a-way-to-destructure-an-object-into-a-new-object-in-es6)

Comment: [Destructuring object and ignore one of the results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37838778/1218980)

Comment: Thank u @EmileBergeron so now `filteredData` should be an array of items needs right?

Comment: Nope, `filteredData` is a new object that only has the properties that were not declared explicitly when destructuring.

Comment: so when I declare a `filteredData` it should be destructuring his properties from state like `const filterD = ({username,....}=state)` cuz when i do it i got a syntax error

Comment: Do _exactly_ like in [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380600/how-can-i-push-the-state-to-an-array-with-specific-items?noredirect=1#comment104953223_59380600).

Comment: OUCH,I think it should be declared before use it

Comment: Yes, [it's a statement, not an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12703214/1218980), so it needs to be on it's own line.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Really thank u very much I learn new things today :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and the [rest parameters syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) if you want to do it without using any library:

```
const { snapshotKey, count, ...rest } = this.state;

...

order.push(rest);
```

Otherwise, you can also use Lodash's [`_.omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) function:

```
order.push(_.omit(this.state, ['snapshotKey', 'count']));
```

Alternatively, if you want to select which properties to use, you can use destructuring again and [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to create the object:

```
const {
    username,
    date,
    time,
    description,
    images,
    buildingNumber,
    status,
    serviceDB,
} = this.state;

...

order.push({
    username,
    date,
    time,
    description,
    images,
    buildingNumber,
    status,
    serviceDB,
});
```

Or, with Lodash, use [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick), which is the opposite of [`_.omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit):

```
order.push(_.pick(this.state, [
    'username',
    'date',
    'time',
    'description',
    'buildingNumber',
    'status',
    'serviceDB',
]));
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, though your answer is exactly the same 3 ways described in the duplicate candidate. We shouldn't answer again if there is already good questions and answers on SO.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I think downvotes should not be allowed without feedback, thus I will re-create answers anytime I find these situations where all posts get a no-comment downvote systematically.

Comment: This will only get your account banned and annoy admins, I don't think it's a good idea in the long run. And forcing a comment when downvoting has already been [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1218980) [a](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/1218980) [lot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/254800).

Comment: (I finally chose to upvote anyway since this is the most complete answer here right now)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select some properties then just declare properties that you want:

```
let {snapshotKey, count, ...y} = state;
arr.push(y);
```

An example:

```js
state = {
    username: '1',
    date: '2',
    time: '3',
    description: '4',
    images: '5',
    buildingNumber: '6',
    status: '7',
    serviceDB: '8',
    snapshotKey: '9', // i don't need this when pushed
    count: -10, // i don't need this when pushed
  };
let arr = [];
let {snapshotKey, count, ...y} = state;
arr.push(y);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Your initial answer was invalid syntax. I removed my downvote, though the question should be closed as a dupe, there are already a lot of similar answers on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Destructuring assignment
As shown in the 
[documentation](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)

```
const {  count,snapshotKey, ...newData } = this.state;
```

Now, newData contains:

```
 newData={
    username: '..',
    date: '..',
    time: '..',
    description: '..',
    images: '..',
    buildingNumber: '..',
    status: '..',
    serviceDB: '..',
  };
```

now use in newData

```
 database()
      .ref(`Providers/ProvidersOrders/${uid}`)
      .push(...newData);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)  [and here](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/object-destructuring-in-es6-3fm) [also here](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f)
plus great examples